# Application.Run(macro) runs successfully in Debug but fails when I run the .exe file from different path folder [WPF application]

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, com

I am facing a peculiar problem, which I didn't think off being a hard to solve bug in the first place.

I have created an excel button for a WPF application, and when clicked the button does the following:

*Method 1*

```cs
//using the OfficeOpenXmland EPPlus packages
public void CreateCopyReportServerNameDB(string sourceFile)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Cover"];
        worksheet.Cells[7, 4].Value = ConnectionDetailsList[0].ToString();
        worksheet.Cells[8, 4].Value = ConnectionDetailsList[1].ToString();

        package.SaveAs(new FileInfo($@"{path}{"file_Report.xlsm"}"));
        package.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*Method 2: Execute Macro*

```cs
public int ExecuteExcelMacro(string sourceFile) //string sourceFile //String.Format("{0}DQTool_Report.xlsm", path)
{
    var destinationFile = @"file_Report";
    Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application
    {
        DisplayAlerts = false,
        Visible = false
    };

    Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook;

    ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sourceFile);

    string macro = "ThisWorkbook.Run_Code";

    try
    {
        ExcelApp.Run(macro);
        Debug.WriteLine("Macro: " + macro + " executed successfully");

        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        ExcelApp.Visible = false;

        ExcelWorkBook.SaveAs($@"{path}{destinationFile}", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        ExcelWorkBook.Close(0);
        if (ExcelWorkBook != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook); }

        ExcelApp.Quit();
        if (ExcelApp != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp); }

        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Macro not run");
        
        //I repeat the Garbage Collector because if the macro fails to execute the excel workbooks remains open.
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        ExcelWorkBook.Close(0);
        if (ExcelWorkBook != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook); }

        ExcelApp.Quit();
        if (ExcelApp != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp); }

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then I combine Methods 1 & 2 under a single button click as follows:

```cs
public string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; //The folder where the .exe file is executed.

private void PreviewExcelReportButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        
        //Method 1: Create copy of standard report file
        CreateCopyReportServerNameDB($@"{path}file.xlsm");

        //Method 2: Run macro
        if (ExecuteExcelMacro($@"{path}file_Report.xlsm") == 0)
            return;

        Debug.WriteLine("End");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }
}
```

Even though the button runs completely successfully when I Debug the application *[the debugger runs in a Desktop folder (shown also in the image below)]*, it rather fails when I move the application folder with all the dll files and the .exe file to a folder location in `C:\`. When the specific button fails to execute the macro of the excel file, the following error is generated:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any comment or thoughts regarding this matter and I am happy to share with you any additional information.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

Excel was automatically disabling all Macros when the Excel file was programmatically opened from a .exe application. So to overpass this I used the below command:

```cs
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application
{
    DisplayAlerts = false,
    Visible = false,
    AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow
};
```

More about MsoAutomationSecurity [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity)